# Set language from menu

Tags: php, internationalization, zend-framework3

I want to change language (set locale) from menu. Translation module already configured. So the code for ex. : `$this->translate('Some Text', 'default', 'de_DE') ?>` is working. But I need to change language from menu. And I used Zend/I18n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have implemented a language changed from a menu. You will need to install the Zend MvcTranslator component

```
public function changeLanguageAction()
{
    $language = $this->params()->fromRoute('lang', 'en');
    //CAN USE PHP setcookie() instead of this
    $this->cookieService->createCookie('xuage', $language, $this->getResponse()->getHeaders());
    //redirect to homepage
    $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
}
```

Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(Event $e)
{
    $app = $e->getParam('application');
    $em = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    //Translation
    $this->initTranslator($e);
}

protected function initTranslator($event)
{
    $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    $lang = @$event->getRequest()->getCookie()->xuage;

    //if language is not set in the cookie, set the default language to english
    if (!$lang) {
        $lang = 'en';
    }

    $translator = $serviceManager->get('MvcTranslator');
    $translator
        ->setLocale($lang)
        ->setFallbackLocale('en');
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to install MvcTranslator but I get `Module (Zend\Mvc\I18n) could not be initialized.` error message
I added `'Zend\Mvc\I18n',` to modules.config.php
Changed Module.php and IndexController as you said
Should I change smth in module.config.php as well?

Comment: you need to add it to composer.json and run composer update then composer install

Comment: and the last thing my routing is like this: 
`'lang' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/:lang',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller'    => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'        => 'index',
                        'lang'          => 'en',
                    ],
                ],
            ],`
but as i understand i need to change it as well right?

Comment: There is some problem its not setting in to the cookie